# Is there a recursive injective and surjective function f:N→PRF?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

It is well known and easy to see that it is possible to effectively number Turing Machine codes. That is, there is an injective and surjective recursive mapping  $g:\mathbb N\to {\rm TM}$: each Turing machine has one and only one number. Then each partial recursive function (${\rm PRF}$) will be represented many times, since each ${\rm PRF}$ is produced by many different ${\rm TM}$s. In fact, Kleene's recursion theorem tells much more about how the same ${\rm PRF}$ occurs. However, the proof of the recursion theorem assumes that for each ${\rm PRF}$ it is possible to find its number  (one of them).

This leaves open the following question. Is there a recursive injective and surjective function $f:\mathbb N\to {\rm PRF}$ ? That is, is there an algorithm that produces for each natural number a ${\rm TM}$ in such a way that each ${\rm PRF}$ is represented exactly once? The answer seems to be no, but why?

Answer (score 3):

I was wrong. It IS possible to recursively list all ${\rm PRF}$ without duplication. See Richard M. Friedberg, Three Theorems on Recursive Enumeration, The Journal of Symbolic Logic, 23,3,1958